# If $ab+bc+ca=1,$ prove $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1+a\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\ge 1+\frac{4}{a+b+c}.$

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> **Problem.** Prove that the following inequality$$\frac{1+a\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1+b\sqrt{ca}}{b+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1+c\sqrt{ab}}{c+\sqrt{ab}}\ge 1+\frac{4}{a+b+c},$$holds for all non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ such that $ab+bc+ca=1.$

---

It is [**Problem 4840, CRUX Mathematicorum.**](https://cms.math.ca/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Wholeissue_49_4.pdf)

I've tried to verify the original form as$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1+a\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+1\right)\ge 4\left(1+\frac{1}{a+b+c}\right),$$$$\iff \sum_{cyc}\frac{(1+a)(1+\sqrt{bc})}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\ge 4\left(1+\frac{1}{a+b+c}\right).$$
I checked the inequality is true:
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1+\sqrt{ca}}{b+\sqrt{ca}}+\frac{1+\sqrt{ab}}{c+\sqrt{ab}}\ge 4.$$
It seems Chebyshev is appropriate $$\sum\limits_{cyc}(1+a);\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1+\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}},$$but I am still stuck here.

Hope to see some ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using your work we'll prove that $$\frac{1+\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\geq\frac{2(b+c)}{a+b+c}.$$
Indeed, we need to prove that
$$(a+b+c)\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}\geq2(b+c)(a+\sqrt{bc})-\sqrt{bc}(a+b+c)$$ or
$$(a+b+c)\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}\geq a(2b-\sqrt{bc}+2c)+\sqrt{bc}(b+c),$$
Which is true by C-S:
$$(a+b+c)\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}=\sqrt{(4ab+4ac+(b+c-a)^2)(ab+ac+bc)}\geq$$
$$\geq2(ab+ac)+\sqrt{bc}(b+c-a)=a(2b-\sqrt{bc}+2c)+\sqrt{bc}(b+c).$$
From here we obtain:
$$\frac{(1+\sqrt{bc})(1+a)}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\geq\frac{2(b+c)(1+a)}{a+b+c}$$ or
$$\frac{(1+\sqrt{bc})(1+a)}{a+\sqrt{bc}}-1\geq\frac{2(b+c)(1+a)}{a+b+c}-1$$ or
$$\frac{1+a\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\geq\frac{b+c-a+2(ab+ac)}{a+b+c},$$ which says:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1+a\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c-a+2(ab+ac)}{a+b+c}=1+\frac{4}{a+b+c}.$$

Comment: (+1) It is nice, indeed.

Comment: Yes, it is nice.

Comment: What is the motivation of first inequality ?

Comment: @TATA box Just $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{2(a+b)}{a+b+c}=4.$ It gives a motivation to prove that $\frac{1+\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\geq\frac{2(b+c)}{a+b+c}$ and it turned out!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, it seems like a miracle.

Comment: @TATA box I agree! This whole area of inequalities is a miracle!

Answer (score 3):

I have read a technical of Khuong Trang called **RAG (Root AM GM)**. Here what it says:

For $x,y,z \ge 0$ then we get
$$\frac{x^2+y}{x+z} \ge 2\left(\sqrt{y+z^2}-z\right).$$
which can be proved by AM GM. Now set
$$(x,y,z) \leftarrow (a,ab+ac,\sqrt{bc})$$
then
$$\frac{a^2+ab+ac}{a+\sqrt{bc}} \ge 2\left(\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-\sqrt{bc}\right),$$
Note that
$$\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-\sqrt{bc} =\frac{ab+ac}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}+\sqrt{bc}},$$
so
$$\frac{a(a+b+c)}{a+\sqrt{bc}} \ge \frac{2a(b+c)}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}+\sqrt{bc}},$$
or
$$\frac{(a+b+c)}{a+\sqrt{bc}} \ge \frac{2(b+c)}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}+\sqrt{bc}},$$
or
$$\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}+\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\ge \frac{2(b+c)}{a+b+c}$$

By the way, I think this is the way how the author created this problem.