# If $x^2+y^2+z^2=1,$ prove $\frac{x(z^2-y^2+2y)}{z}+\frac{y(x^2-z^2+2z)}{x}+\frac{z(y^2-x^2+2x)}{y}\ge 2$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

Let $x,y,z>0: x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Prove that$$\frac{x(z^2-y^2+2y)}{z}+\frac{y(x^2-z^2+2z)}{x}+\frac{z(y^2-x^2+2x)}{y}\ge 2$$
I tried to use AM-GM $$\frac{x(z^2-y^2+2y)}{z}+\frac{y(x^2-z^2+2z)}{x}+\frac{z(y^2-x^2+2x)}{y}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{x(z^2-y^2+2y)}{z}.\frac{y(x^2-z^2+2z)}{x}.\frac{z(y^2-x^2+2x)}{y}}=3\sqrt[3]{(z^2-y^2+2y)(x^2-z^2+2z)(y^2-x^2+2x)}.$$
Now, how to prove $$(z^2-y^2+2y)(x^2-z^2+2z)(y^2-x^2+2x)\ge \frac{8}{27}. \tag{1}$$Also, by $x=y=z=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},$ is the following true ? $$(z^2-y^2+2y)(x^2-z^2+2z)(y^2-x^2+2x)\ge\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{9}.\tag{2}$$
I need a proof for $(1),(2).$ Furthermore, is there other ideas? Thank you for sharings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

*Remark.* In general, my proof is similar to Michael Rozenberg's proof. Anyway, I found it independently, so I posted it.

Due to the given condition, the OP can be rewritten as$$\frac{x(z^2-y^2)}{z}+\frac{y(x^2-z^2)}{x}+\frac{z(y^2-x^2)}{y}\ge 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-\frac{xy}{z}-\frac{yz}{x}-\frac{zx}{y}\right). \tag{*}$$
Now, denoting $ab=x^2;bc=y^2;ca=z^2 \implies x,y,z\ge 0; a=\dfrac{zx}{y}>0,b=\dfrac{yx}{z}>0,c=\dfrac{zy}{x}>0.$

It is easily to make the inequality to$$(a-b)\sqrt{bc}+(b-c)\sqrt{ca}+(c-a)\sqrt{ab}\ge 2\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}(\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-a-b-c). \tag{*}$$
WLOG, assume $a\ge b\ge c\ge 0.$

Apply [Michael Rozenberg's CBS using](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746581/if-abbcca-1-prove-sum-cyc-frac1a-sqrtbca-sqrtbc-ge-1-frac4), we obtain$$(a+b+c)\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}\ge \sqrt{ab}(a+b-c)+2c(a+b). $$$$(a+b+c)\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}\ge \sqrt{ac}(a+c-b)+2b(a+c).$$
It implies\begin{align*}
    &2(a+b+c)\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}\\&\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)+2bc+\left(a\sqrt{ab}+c\sqrt{ca}\right)+\left(b\sqrt{ab}+a\sqrt{ca}\right)-\sqrt{abc}(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}).
\end{align*}
Id est, it is enough to prove that$$\sqrt{ab}(a+b)+\sqrt{ca}(c+a)-\sqrt{abc}(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})\ge (a-b)\sqrt{bc}+(b-c)\sqrt{ca}+(c-a)\sqrt{ab}.$$This inequality is equivalent to$$ \sqrt{ab}(2a+b-c)+\sqrt{ca}(2c+a-b)+2bc\ge \sqrt{bc}(a-b)+\sqrt{abc}(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}),$$$$\iff 2bc+2c\sqrt{ca}+(a-b)(\sqrt{ca}-\sqrt{bc})+\sqrt{ab}(2a+b-2c-\sqrt{bc})\ge0,$$which is obvious by $a\ge b\ge c\ge 0.$

Hence, $(*)$ is proven. The proof is done.

Answer (score 3):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x(z^2-y^2)}{z}+2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{z}\geq2(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$
or
$$2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^3z^2+2x^3yz-x^2y^2z)$$ and since by AM-G (or by Rearrangement) $$\sum_{cyc}(x^3y^2-x^2y^2z)\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that:
$$2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^3y^2+x^3z^2+2x^3yz-2x^2y^2z).$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove a linear inequality of $w^3$.

But a linear function gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $w^3$, which by $uvw$ happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $z\rightarrow0^+$ and $y=1$.

Thus, we obtain:
$$2x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}\geq x^3+x^2$$ or
$$4(x^2+1)\geq(x+1)^2,$$ which is true by C-S:
$$4(x^2+1)>(1+1)(x^2+1)\geq(x+1)^2.$$
2. Two variables are equal.

Let $y=z=1$,

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$2(2x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+2}\geq2(x^3+x^2+1)+2x(x^2+2)-2x(x+2)$$ or
$$(2x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+2}\geq2x^3+1$$ or
$$12x^4-4x^3+9x^2+1\geq0,$$  which is obvious.

About $uvw$ see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: A good proof, I upvoted. When does equality hold ? Is $2$ is exactly mimium ?

Comment: @Inequality The equality does not occur.  I think we can take a less value, but for which symmetrization does not help.

Comment: Wow, it is nice @MichaelRozenberg. The AM-GM step $x^3y^2+y^3z^2+z^3x^2\ge xyz(xy+yz+zx)$ is an art, indeed. By adding a intermediate cyclic inequality, the symmetrical consequence follows! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Using $x \ge x^2$, $y \ge y^2$ and $z \ge z^2$,
it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{x(z^2 + y)}{z} + \frac{y(x^2 + z)}{x} + \frac{z(y^2 + x)}{y} \ge 2$$
or
$$(xy + yz + zx)xyz + x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 \ge 2xyz$$
or (using $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$)
$$(xy + yz + zx)xyz + x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 \ge 2xyz(x^2 + y^2 + z^2). \tag{1}$$

WLOG, assume that $x \ge y \ge z$. Using $x \le 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(xy + yz + zx)xyz + x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 - 2xyz(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)\\
 \ge{}& (xy + yz + zx)xyz + (x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2)x - 2xyz(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)\\
 ={}& x\Big((y - z)^2x^2 + (y + z)yz \cdot x - 2yz(y^2 - yz + z^2)\Big)\\
 \ge{}& x\Big((y - z)^2\cdot y^2 + (y + z)yz \cdot y - 2yz(y^2 - yz + z^2)\Big)\\
 ={}& xy (y - z)(y^2 - 2yz + 2z^2)\\
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}
(*Note*: Acutally, (1) is true for all $x, y, z\in [0, 1]$.)

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

By my previous post we need to prove that:

$$2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^3z^2+2x^3yz-x^2y^2z).$$
Now, let $x=\max\{x,y,z\}.$

Thus, by C-S
$$2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2=2\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2)^2}=$$
$$=2\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)((x^2y^2+x^2z^2-y^2z^2)^2+4x^2y^2z^2(y^2+z^2))}\geq$$
$$\geq2\left(x(x^2y^2+x^2z^2-y^2z^2)+2xyz(y^2+z^2)\right)$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$2x^3y^2+2x^3z^2-2y^2z^2x+4y^3xz+4z^3xy\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^3z^2+2x^3yz-x^2y^2z)$$ or
$$2x^3y^2+x^3z^2-y^2z^2x+x^2y^2z+x^2z^2y+2y^3xz+2z^3xy-2x^3yz-y^3x^2-z^3y^2\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$x^3y^2+x^3z^2-2x^3yz=x^3(y-z)^2\geq0,$$
$$x^3y^2\geq y^3x^2,$$ $$z^3xy\geq z^3y^2$$ and $$x^2z^2y\geq y^2z^2x.$$

Comment: Very good one! Thanks

Comment: @Inequality You are welcome!

Comment: I found a proof which quite similar to yours @MichaelRozenberg. I posted it below